# Is there a way to get the worksheet names from 20MB+ Excel files with PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, large-files

I am using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to read data out of Excel files.

With the following code, I am able to read **one particular worksheet** out of a **3MB** Excel file in just a couple seconds. Works nicely.

However, I now have **27MB** and **88MB** Excel files which I need to get data out of. They are so large that even **OpenOffice** cannot open them.

I have found that I can use an index number instead of a name when I load a sheet, but this seems inconsistent, e.g. in one particular Excel file `setLoadSheetsOnly(0)` gave me the **third** sheet while `setLoadSheetsOnly(1)` gave me an **error** even though there were four worksheets in the file. So that seems **unreliable** for some reason.

**Is there a way I can read out the names of the worksheets from a large file so that I can access only one of its worksheets at a time?**

```
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile("data/" . $file_name);
        $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(array($sheet_name));
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("data/" . $file_name);

        echo '<table border="1">';
        for ($row = 1; $row < $number_of_rows; $row++) {
            echo '<tr>';
            for ($column = 0; $column < $number_of_columns; $column++) {
                $value = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getCellByColumnAndRow($column, $row)->getValue();
                echo '<td>';
                echo $value . '&nbsp;';
                echo '</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
        die;
```

## ADDENDUM:

I found some code that gets close, but it doesn't seem to always be accurate, e.g. here it missed the second worksheet in a 27MB file:

[image]

and here it only got the third worksheet and missed 3 others:

[image]

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile("data/" . $file_name);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(0);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("data/" . $file_name);

echo $objPHPExcel->getSheetCount(), ' worksheets<hr/>';
$loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcel->getSheetNames();
foreach ($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
    echo $sheetIndex, ' -> ', $loadedSheetName, '<br />';
}
die;
```

Comment: Watch out for sheet names containing a ! as this is used in Excel when referencing a cell including the worksheet name. e.g. 'DAUER!'!A1 and while any formula using references like this should work, there is the possibility of errors in the calculation engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to read the names of the worksheets without loading the whole file.

Using an index number rather than a name when calling setLoadSheetsOnly() won't give a predictable result: the code logic that performs that check uses in_array() to test if the sheetname that it is about to read is in the array of sheetnames to read. e.g.

```
// check if sheet should be skipped
if (isset($this->_loadSheetsOnly) && !in_array($sheet['name'], $this->_loadSheetsOnly)) {
    continue;
}
```

I would suspect that the comparison of a string against a numeric value will be giving a true result for 0 == "mySheetName" when executing this test (based on PHP's loose typing and comparison casting rules).

I could probably provide a Reader method that would return a list of worksheet names without actually loading the entire file, although there would be a performance hit involved.

**EDIT**

If you add the following method to Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/Excel2007.php

```
/**
 * Reads names of the worksheets from a file, without loading the whole file to a PHPExcel object
 *
 * @param   string      $pFilename
 * @throws  Exception
 */
public function listWorksheetNames($pFilename)
{
    // Check if file exists
    if (!file_exists($pFilename)) {
        throw new Exception("Could not open " . $pFilename . " for reading! File does not exist.");
    }

    $worksheetNames = array();

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($pFilename);

    $rels = simplexml_load_string($this->_getFromZipArchive($zip, "_rels/.rels")); //~ http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships");
    foreach ($rels->Relationship as $rel) {
        switch ($rel["Type"]) {
            case "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument":
                $xmlWorkbook = simplexml_load_string($this->_getFromZipArchive($zip, "{$rel['Target']}"));  //~ http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main");

                if ($xmlWorkbook->sheets) {
                    foreach ($xmlWorkbook->sheets->sheet as $eleSheet) {
                        // Check if sheet should be skipped
                        $worksheetNames[] = (string) $eleSheet["name"];
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    $zip->close();

    return $worksheetNames;
}
```

You can call it by using:

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = 'biostat-behfisk-2005.xlsx';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$worksheetNames = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($inputFileName);

foreach ($worksheetNames as $sheetName) {
    echo $sheetName, '<br />';
}
```

the returned $worksheetNames should contain an array of all worksheet names as UTF-8 strings. Because it's only reading the absolute minimum from the .xlsx to retrieve these names, it should be fairly fast. I'll do some more tests before checking it into the PHPExcel SVN, but (for now) it seems to do what you need.

**EDIT2**

Equivalent method for the Excel5 Reader

```
/**
 * Reads names of the worksheets from a file, without loading the whole file to a PHPExcel object
 *
 * @param   string      $pFilename
 * @throws  Exception
 */
public function listWorksheetNames($pFilename)
{
    // Check if file exists
    if (!file_exists($pFilename)) {
        throw new Exception("Could not open " . $pFilename . " for reading! File does not exist.");
    }

    $worksheetNames = array();

    // Read the OLE file
    $this->_loadOLE($pFilename);

    // total byte size of Excel data (workbook global substream + sheet substreams)
    $this->_dataSize = strlen($this->_data);

    $this->_pos     = 0;
    $this->_sheets  = array();

    // Parse Workbook Global Substream
    while ($this->_pos < $this->_dataSize) {
        $code = self::_GetInt2d($this->_data, $this->_pos);

        switch ($code) {
            case self::XLS_Type_BOF:    $this->_readBof();      break;
            case self::XLS_Type_SHEET:  $this->_readSheet();    break;
            case self::XLS_Type_EOF:    $this->_readDefault();  break 2;
            default:                    $this->_readDefault();  break;
        }
    }

    foreach ($this->_sheets as $sheet) {
        if ($sheet['sheetType'] != 0x00) {
            // 0x00: Worksheet, 0x02: Chart, 0x06: Visual Basic module
            continue;
        }

        $worksheetNames[] = $sheet['name'];
    }

    return $worksheetNames;
}
```

Not as efficient as the Excel2007 Reader version, but should still be faster than parsing the whole .xls file just for the sheet names because I'm only parsing the global stream.

Comment: The code that I posted above is able to get the names of the worksheets out of a 27MB Excel file in less than 10 seconds, so that is tolerable. However, it doesn't seem to be accurate, i.e. missed one of the worksheets, is there something I'm not specifying correctly in the code?

Comment: I posted a second screenshot of it missing three worksheets in a 3MB file. Is there a way I can make the worksheet name reading more accurate?

Comment: Based on the PHP casting rules... you're setting $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(0); before loading the file. With loose typing, 'CODE' == 0 and 'DAUER!' == 0, but '4C ISO' != 0 ('4C ISO' == 4). If you didn't set $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(0); then PHPExcel wouldn't do this test, and all sheets would be loaded, and $objPHPExcel->getSheetNames() would return the full list.

Comment: The worksheets beginning 2010 are missing because of the casting rules... string '2010 whatever' is being compared with numeric 0, and PHP will cast the string to a number for the comparison test, so 2010 != 0, while 'Papier whatever' will cast to 0 for the comparison, returning a true.

Comment: that makes sense, it's finding all the worksheets now, but now to get the worksheet names out of the 3MB file it takes 1min 19sec which would make a file that is 80MB+ approx 30 minutes which is too long. If you were able to create a specific reader to only get the worksheet names out of any size file in under 10 seconds, that would be very useful!

Comment: I'd need to write a new method for the Readers to do that... what format Excel file are you reading? .xls or .xlsx?

Comment: actually both, which is one reason I like your library, it seems to read and write to Excel95 and 2007 without any problems. At the moment the two 50MB+ files are both .xlsx

Comment: I'll be quicker writing a method for the Excel2007, should be able to knock something up this afternoon, Excel5 will take longer, and I'd want to provide the same function in the Excel2003XML, OOCalc and Gnumeric Readers as well (for consistency) but imagine you don't need these, so no need for speed with writing those. Will see what I can do for you.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. It's currently the large .xlsx files that are the problem since I can't access the worksheets unless I know what they are named and don't want to be dependent on having Excel installed everywhere. And OpenOffice has a hard time with these large files as it is.

Comment: @Edward - Here's the code for a listWorksheetNames() method for the Excel2007 Reader

Comment: Code for the listWorksheetNames() method for all Readers that support multiple-worksheet workbooks (Excel2007, Excel5, Excel2003XML, OOCalc and Gnumeric) are all now in the PHPExcel SVN repository

Comment: Thanks Mark, I downloaded the patch and it now reads the worksheets out of a 3MB Excel5 file and a 87MB Excel2007 file in less than a second, very nice, here's the link to the patch for others: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/66096

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to amend phpexcel so I went with this:

```
public function getWorksheetNames($pFilename) {

    $worksheetNames = array ();

    $zip = zip_open ( $pFilename );
    while ( $entry = zip_read ( $zip ) ) {

        $entry_name = zip_entry_name ( $entry );
        if ($entry_name == 'xl/workbook.xml') {
            if (zip_entry_open ( $zip, $entry, "r" )) {
                $buf = zip_entry_read ( $entry, zip_entry_filesize ( $entry ) );
                $workbook = simplexml_load_string ( $buf );
                foreach ( $workbook->sheets as $sheets ) {
                    foreach( $sheets as $sheet) {
                        $attributes=$sheet->attributes();
                        $worksheetNames[]=$attributes['name'];
                    }
                }
                zip_entry_close ( $entry );
            }
            break;
        }

    }
    zip_close ( $zip );
    return $worksheetNames;
}
```

It only works on excel 2007 or later but did what I needed